# How to apply onfocus function to all "input" objects?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to create an onfocus function to my input fields in a form. I'm working with a drag and drop landing page wizard(in Marketo) therefore I don't have access to the HTML tags.

I tried to do use getElementById and it worked only on the first field. I also tried the following:

```
<script>
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
input.onfocus = function() {

    this.value=''


}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You query for all the `<input>`s elements, but work only with the first match:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
```

Iterate over all the matches and do your magic:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0; i< inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].onfocus = function(){this.value = '';};
}
```

If you can use jQuery, it's a lot easier:

```
$('input').focus(function(){this.value = '';});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another variant would be this](http://jsfiddle.net/t5WN2/)

```
    //get all inputs
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
    //cache the length
  , inputsLen = inputs.length;

//define one handler
function focusHandler(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

//loop through all
while(inputsLen--){
  //each element's onfocus references only one function instead of "one each"
  inputs[inputsLen].onfocus = focusHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yea ,in jquery you can do it like:

```
$("input").on("focus",function(){
    //function data block goes here    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone beat me to it but try this

```
$("input").on("focus",function()
{
    this.value=''  
});
```